# Is it possible to make a GUI window using the Autokey API?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, autokey

My autokey crashes if I run a script from the GUI via tkinter.
It gives this error. It doesn’t seem to say anything about the GUI, but personally I think it’s because of it, because if I run simpler scripts (without GUI), then everything works fine and doesn’t close (as far as I remember).
Does the Autokey API have the ability to create a GUI? - I looked in their [wiki](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/API-Examples) and [documentation](https://autokey.github.io/api.html), but didn't find anything
I found another similar error from [another person](https://github.com/asweigart/PyMsgBox/issues/9), but no one has given a solution to it yet
Experts, I will be very grateful to you

```
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread Fatal Python error: Aborted

Thread 0x00007fa2c3fff640 (most recent call first):   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyinotify.py", line 1194 in check_events   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/monitor.py", line 125 in run   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016 in _bootstrap_inner File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fa2e2b84640 (most recent call first):   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 320 in wait   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/queue.py", line 171 in get   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/iomediator/_iomediator.py", line 103 in run   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016 in _bootstrap_inner   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fa2e3385640 (most recent call first):   File "/home/fedor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 511 in send_and_recv   File "/home/fedor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/rq.py", line 1493 in reply   File "/home/fedor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/rq.py", line 1481 in __init__   File "/home/fedor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/ext/record.py", line 215 in __init__   File "/home/fedor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/ext/record.py", line 234 in enable_context   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 1206 in run   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016 in
_bootstrap_inner   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fa2e3c86640 (most recent call first):   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 906 in
__flushEvents   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953 in run   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016 in
_bootstrap_inner   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00007fa2e4487640 (most recent call first):   Garbage-collecting   File "/home/fedor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 463 in send_and_recv   File "/home/fedor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/rq.py", line 1493 in reply   File "/home/fedor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/rq.py", line 1481 in __init__   File "/home/fedor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/xobject/drawable.py", line 435 in get_property   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 1145 in
_try_read_property   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 1128 in
_try_get_window_title   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 1080 in
_get_window_info   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 1074 in get_window_info   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 429 in
__recurseTreeUngrab   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 418 in
__ungrabAllHotkeys   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 242 in
__eventLoop   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953 in run   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016 in _bootstrap_inner File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fa2e7bfd000 (most recent call first):   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 1689 in main   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/gtkapp.py", line 273 in main   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/gtkui/__main__.py", line 9 in main   File "/usr/bin/autokey-gtk", line 33 in <module>

Extension modules: _dbus_bindings, _dbus_glib_bindings, gi._gi, cairo._cairo, gi._gi_cairo, PIL._imaging (total: 6) Aborted (core dumped)
```